# if condition is met but contents of if statement don't seem to execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, null, conditional-statements

I am trying to do an if/else statement where it checks to see if an array is empty. It seems like the first condition is evaluated and not met, and so it moves to the else and executes. This is the output on the screen (iOS):

[image]

The name that you see is there because the else statement gets executed. However there are 3 other usernames with scores of 0 which aren't getting displayed. Here is the relevant conditional:

```
NSArray *keyArray = [yy allKeys];
for(NSString *keyd in keyArray) {
    NSLog(@"yy objectforkey *********: %@", [[yy objectForKey:keyd] debugDescription]);

    if(![yy objectForKey:keyd]){

        NSMutableDictionary* entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        NSLog(@"inside yy object for key count 0 *****####***##*#*#*#");
        [tableData addObject:keyd];
        [matchesForUser addObject:@"0"];
        entry[@"username"] = keyd;
        entry[@"matches"] = @"0";
        [entries addObject:entry];
    }

    else {
        NSMutableArray *locs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[yy objectForKey:keyd]];
        //NSString *outerouter;
        //NSNumber *outeroutermatches = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        for(NSDictionary *outterar in locs) {

            NSMutableDictionary* entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];

            NSLog(@"%@ outtererjar descriptiong ##(#(#(#(#(#(#(#(#(#((#", [outterar description]);

            entry[@"username"] = keyd;

            entry[@"matches"] = [outterar valueForKey:@"groupmatches"];

            if([entries count] > 0) {
                for(int counter = 0; counter < [entries count]; counter++) {
                    if([[[entries objectAtIndex:counter] valueForKey:@"matches"] intValue] < [[entry valueForKey:@"matches"] intValue]) {
                        NSLog(@"GETTING IN IFFFFFF ABOOOVVEEEEE ******8888888*********");

                        //NSMutableDictionary *stud = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:keyd, @"username", nil];
                        [matchesForUser addObject:[outterar objectForKey:@"groupmatches"]];
                        [tableData addObject:keyd];

                        NSLog(@"%@ WHAT IS ENTRIES>>>!!!!??!?!?!", [[entries objectAtIndex:counter] valueForKey:@"username"]);
                        if([keyd isEqualToString:[[entries objectAtIndex:counter] valueForKey:@"username"]]) {
                            NSLog(@"GETTING IN IFFFFFF ******8888888*********");
                            [entries removeObjectAtIndex:counter];
                            [entries insertObject:entry atIndex:counter];
                        }
                        else {
                            [entries addObject:entry];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        [entries addObject:entry];
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                [matchesForUser addObject:[outterar objectForKey:@"groupmatches"]];
                [tableData addObject:keyd];
                [entries addObject:entry];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`_tableViewScore` and `tableData` are both arrays which are used to populate the `UIScrollView`(s). The code inside the if statement should execute every time an empty object is found (they are arrays). The else runs, that is why you see the username with the score, but it seems like the if isn't getting executed when the array is null.

When I output the object I am checking for, an empty object looks like this:

```
yy objectforkey *********: <__NSArrayM 0x170454cd0>(

)
```

I just need to be able to identify when one of the objects is like that. Thanks!

Comment: can i get an explanation for the -1?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
![yy objectForKey:keyd]
```

checks

> does the key `keyd` not exist in the dictionary

which is of course always `false` because all keys returned by the property `allKeys` are guaranteed to exist and a value for an existing key cannot be `nil` by definition.

If you want to check if the array is empty you have to write

```
![[yy objectForKey:keyd] count]
```

PS: Consider to use more descriptive variable naming rather than `yy`

Comment: This answer makes more sense if you mention the fact that you can't store a `nil` value for a key in `NSDictionary`.

Comment: thanks guys...yah sometimes i get hasty with the variable names - ill try and do better ;)

Comment: I thought you were right..but now i notice the problem happens when I exit the app, then enter the app, then try and access the scoreboard....if i am already in the app and select the scoreboard it works fine.

Comment: i think it has something to do with my counter for loop - trying to figure it out